# Windows Server 2008 R2: Cannot access event viewer, server manager, IIS7 CLSID:FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb}

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am currently running Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I try to run Event Viewer, I get "MMC cannot initialize the snap-in".

When I try to run IIS7, I get "Please set registry key HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot to point to the .NET Framework install location"

And when I try to open server manager I get: MMC Could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: Server Manager
CLSID:FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb}

I've tried:

- running the .net repair tool.
- I can't reinstall .net 3.5 b/c it requires the server manager to do so.
- ive done the machine.config rename

Answer (score 0):

I copied the Microsoft.Net folder from a working server to the affected server and resolved this issue.